# Android no envía datos a MySQL

Tags: php, java, mysql, android

Tengo un login en java para android, cuando ingreso los datos este debe tomar los datos de la base de datos en mysql mediante un archivo en php y confirmar si son correctos, si son correctos pasa a otra actividad.

La aplicación funciona en mi computadora personal de mi casa pero no funciona en la computadora del lugar en el que trabajo y no se por qué.

Aquí el código php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ident']) && isset($_REQUEST['clave']))
{
    $ident=$_REQUEST['ident'];
    $clave=$_REQUEST['clave'];
    $conn =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdbanco");
    $registros=$conn->query("select ident,nombres,email,clave from cliente where ident = '$ident' and clave = '$clave'");
    //Aquí encripto los datos en json para pasarlos a android
    $json = array();
    foreach ($registros as $fila) 
    {
        $json['datos'][]=$fila;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
else
{
    echo "Ingrese la identificación y la clave";
}
```

Y aquí el código de java

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    //Se utiliza la clase usuario para tomar los campos del arreglo datos del archivo php
    cliente usua = new cliente();
    //datos: arreglo que envía los datos en formato JSON, en el archivo php
    JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("datos");
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);//posición 0 del arreglo....
        usua.setIdent(jsonObject.optString("ident"));
        usua.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombres"));
        usua.setCorreo(jsonObject.optString("email"));
        usua.setClave(jsonObject.optString("clave"));

    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(),logeado.class);
    intencion.putExtra(logeado.nombre,usua.getNombre());
    startActivity(intencion);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se ha encontrado al usuario"+ident.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void iniciarsesion()
{
    //Aquí debo ingresar la ip de la computadora que estoy utilizando, despues el puerto(estoy usando xampp con el puerto 8080) y la dirección php
    String url = "http://192.168.2.109:8080/banco/database.php?ident="+ident.getText().toString()+"&clave="+clave.getText().toString();
    jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    rq.add(jrq);
}
```

Como ya os dije el código funciona bien en unas computadoras pero en otra no, probé el archivo de php individualmente para confirmar que funcionara. También agregué el permission.INTERNET en el manifest.

Edit: Para los que preguntan, esto es lo que tengo con rq y jrq que aparecen al final, hice el código hace tiempo así que no recuerdo muy bien que hacen

```
//Esto lo hice al definir los objetos que necesitaba para la conexión
    RequestQueue rq;
    JsonRequest jrq;

//Esto lo hice después con el objeto definido
    rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

//Y esto es el final del código
    jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    rq.add(jrq);
```

Si no recuerdo mal rq manda un mensaje en json y jrq lo convierte en un objeto, o algo así.

Comment: fijate que este servidor donde no te da en verdad sus credenciales sean estas:

Host: localhost user: root pass: , db: bdbanco

Comment: @AnySlehider Las credenciales son correctas, estoy usando una base de datos local con xampp y la importé desde el pc en el que funciona.

Comment: que response te da la conexion JsonObjectRequest?

Comment: @Jeremy que obtienes como valor de la variable "response" en el método onResponse() ? regularmente el problema es debido a que los datos no se reciben en la respuesta.

Comment: @Jorgesys Al presionar un botón este llama al public void iniciarsesion, el cual contiene la dirección del archivo php para iniciar sesion. Si encuentra los datos especificados activa el OnResponse que trae los datos de la base de datos y pasa a otra actividad, si no encuentra los datos activa el OnErrorResponse y envía un mensaje de error

Comment: Si dices que en unos equipos funciona y en otros no, es muy probable que el problema esté aquí: `String url = "http://192.168.2.109:8080/banco/database.php?ident="+ident.getText().toString()+"&clave="+clave.getText().toString();`, esta es una URL local (supongo): `http://192.168.2.109:8080/banco/database.php` puede que el puerto `8080`esté bloqueado en esos equipos, o que la IP sea otra, o que no exista en esos equipos la carpeta `banco` en esa dirección.